# How to split comma delimited list of strings in oracle plsql, when the individual string itself is having comma in it?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Table T1

```
C1   |  C2
-----+------
A,B  |  C,D
```

Code:

```
DECLARE
    l_varchar VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT C1||','||C2 INTO l_varchar FROM T1;
END;
```

Now I need to split values in l_varchar based on COMMA delimiter.

If I try to split as given in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b42db/7

I get:

```
A
B
C
D
```

But I need:

```
A,B
C,D
```

Can you please help me to get this desired output.

Can I do something while concatenating the strings, so that later I will be able to split it?

Below query is used to concatenate, can this be tweaked?

```
SELECT C1||','||C2 INTO l_varchar FROM T1;
```

Query used to split comma delimited string:

```
select 
    regexp_substr(C1||','||c2 ,'[^,]+', 1, level) As str 
from 
    (select 'A,B' c1, 'C,D' c2 from dual)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(C1||','||c2, ',') + 1
```

Comment: How is a mindless "thing" (such as a computer and the software running on it) supposed to differentiate between the commas in the original string and the comma you added to combine the two strings into a single one? The short answer is IT CAN'T BE DONE. Even you as a thinking person can't split the string 'A,B,C,D' into 'A,B' and 'C,D' and not, for example, 'A' and 'B,C,D' without more information.

Comment: To illustrate the issue further: I give you the number 15. Split it into the two original numbers. I arrived at the number 15 by adding two numbers, but you don't know what numbers I added. You don't even know that I arrived at the number 15 by adding two numbers, or by any other method; all you see is the number 15, and you must split it into two numbers, but you MUST somehow split it into the two numbers I added in the first place. You don't know if I added 12 + 3 or 6 + 9, you only see "15", but somehow you must find out what I added to get 15.

Comment: Use a pipe instead of comma?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding, what you are trying to do is not possible unless you use a different delimiter. Example :

```
SELECT C1||';'||C2 INTO l_varchar FROM T1;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a very nice and correct way to do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1
UNPIVOT (unpivoted_column FOR original_column 
         IN (c1 AS 'C1', c2 AS 'C2'));
```

For any further clarifications don't hesitate to ask me.

Ted.

Answer (score 0):

Best possible way is to use the REGEXP combinations. Hope the below snippet helps you to get the desired result.

```
SELECT regexp_substr(a.c, '[^*]+', 1, level) TXT
FROM
  (SELECT COL1
    ||'*'
    ||COL2
    ||'*'
    ||COL3 C
  FROM
    (SELECT 'A,B' COL1,'C,D' COL2,'E,F' COL3 FROM DUAL
    )
  )A
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(A.C)-LENGTH(REPLACE(A.C,'*',''))+1;
```